# How do I update pins on a MKMapView as a user moves

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I query a database for store information. I want stores to appear on screen within a certain radius around the user's current location. I want new stores to appear on screen as the user moves without the user having to manually refresh anything. What delegate method should I use to query for stores in and to place them on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to implement only `func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?` and listen location changes with CLLocation Manager.Whenever new location appear query point of interests and append to mapview by `addAnnotations`.After than set mapview centerCoordinate property to reveal user current position in mapview

Answer (score 1):

You can get the coordinates of the point at the center of the map using `centerCoordinate`

```
 var coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(map.centerCoordinate.latitude, map.centerCoordinate.longitude)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [Tracking the User Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204-CH3-SW12) for MKMapView using its delegates.

For location update [MKMapViewDelagate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204-CH3-SW2)'s

[- mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:)

To place them on screen remove the previous annotation and add new annotations fetched from your query.